# set the language of iis

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, windows-vista

is there any way to make IIS language as English? my OS is currently in Turkish so the IIS is.

My OS is windows vista home premium so AFAIK, I cannot change the language of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set English as the display language in the OS. You can do that in the Control Panel -> Region And Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Display language (at least that is what it is in English.). Vista Ultimate will let you add any language pack for free. The other versions probably require a small payment for each additional language.

Comment: thanks. I guess home premium doesn't support multiple languages.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work, I have Windows 7 ultimate with the English language pack.

Comment: It sucks because my windows8 used to be Swedish, but i changed the OS language to English. My whole OS UI is perfectly in English but somehow the IIS interface is in Swedish again... I always get annoyed by those language problems. How hard is it to just serve my software in English...

Comment: I know it's old but if you run IIS as Administrator on non admin account, this admin account also have to has set English as display language

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the following article:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836%28WS.10%29.aspx

Looks like you can change the globalization settings of .Net, but not sure about the UI for IIS.  Since it is pretty well engrained within the operating system, you may have to change your system settings.  Again, not 100% sure, but seems logical.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8, in IIS, click on the website name and then go to **.NET Globalization**, and select the desired language. The answer from Thomas doesn't work for IIS.